# How would I go about creating an android app that displays tables of data from an SQL Server?

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make an android application that displays tables of sorted data which is stored on a 2008 MS SQL Server. I already thoroughly googled this issue and essentially every person who wanted to connect to a server directly through Android was told they should make a web service which bridges the app with the database server. Problem is, I have no clue how to do that. I only have (v. limited) java/android knowledge.

Instead, I was hoping that the data on the server could somehow be stored locally on the phone and used by the app, instead of connecting to the server directly, which is slow and insecure. (This is a HUGE database we're talking about - 100,000s of entries) Would that be feasible at all?

---

Comment: Storing a huge db on phone is not advisable either. You'll need a web service in between the app and db. You cannot escape that.

Comment: Could I store only certain data from the database?

Comment: A question like this, requesting that we recommend a tool/approach to achieving something is very likely to solicit a number of strong opinions from the community who may favor one tool/approach over the other. 
A general guide is to avoid such questions and rather ask a more specific question about a problem you are encountering.

Comment: You can store the database locally in the asset folder of your app and make it smaller by cuting it in different parts and zipping it. The problem is, each time you want to update it you will have to make a new version of the app and publish it again

Comment: By the way hundreds of thousands of rows is not HUGE.  Billions of rows would be huge.  Though it's possible your db is too big to manage well with SQLite.  I would search for information about large sqlite databases.  And accessing a remote database is not insecure if done correctly.